# With all Firebase products, Is it possible to return a positive integer with out repeat

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Same as SQL, you can add a new row with the primary key being auto incremental.

We need a counter where we can get unique values ​​even if we call them at the same time. (the result should be **n** and **n+1**)

Is it possible for all firebase products to create a counter that returns you a value that is never the same?

#### Eg.

- It's possible to tell that user from firebase authentication is the first, second or third from a register (the sequence should never change) if it's so it would be great
- A counter that gives you a number that never is the same even I and others request at the same time.

#### Main purpose

- I want a 1-1 map, a positive integer (UInt32) to firebase account UID

  - eg. 1: aksd12391, 2: da1293nvs1dks, 4: 1is91jesoc

#### Using Transaction's Firestore (Concurrency)

It still returns the same not unique

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a counter that
> returns you a value that is never the same?

Yes, you can use a numeric field in a Firestore document that you (transactionally) increment as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?authuser=0#increment_a_numeric_value) in the doc.

> It's possible to tell that user from Firebase authentication is the
> first, second or third from a register (the sequence should never
> change)

Yes, you can assign a unique value (obtained as explained above) to a user, by, for example, saving a user profile in Firestore and assigning this value as a "functional" id.

Comment: I take your advice but unfortunately I got the result that's not unique when I call .runTransaction() 10 times concurrently (I added the detail)